# How to centralise a complete website made with absolute positioned divs?

Tags: html, position, centering, absolute

I have made a site on dreamweaver by drawing `div`s on `absolute` position but it only looks centered on a `1280px` wide monitor and can't seem to make a parent `#wrap` `div` to host all the absolute position `div`s.

Here is the code that I made,

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrap_main {
 position: absolute;
top: 0px;
z-index: 2;
width:1400px;
margin-left:-200px;
left:50%;
text-aling:left;
}

body {
background-color: #000000;
}
#Layer1 {
position:relative;
left:34px;
top:32px;
width:156px;
height:102px;
z-index:1;
}
#Layer2 {
position:relative;
left:37px;
top:136px;
width:104px;
height:32px;
z-index:2;
}
#Layer3 {
position:relative;
left:140px;
top:136px;
width:104px;
height:33px;
z-index:3;
}
```

Here is the HTML content showing my parent div and the sub div ids that I wish to wrap.

```
<div id="wrap_main">
<div id="Layer25"></div>
<div id="Layer37">`<img src="../Beer_n_tts_website/Images/blue_wood.jpg" alt="Blue Wood"     width="200" height="634" longdesc="Blue wood background for beer n tts" /></div>
<div id="Layer38"><a href="../Beer_n_tts_website/index.html"><img  src="../Beer_n_tts_website/Images/beerntts_logo.png" alt="beer n tts logo" width="118"  height="82" border="0" longdesc="beer and tts logo no background" /></a></div>'
```

After looking for centering `div`s here I can't seem to find an answer that will work for all the `div`s I've made, just to have a `#wrap` or a class.

Answer (score 0):

**Details:** if you just wanted it centered the below will work

css

```
#wrap_main { text-align: center }
```

html

```
<div id="wrap_main" >
    Other Div's
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @MVCkarl - it did not work how ever i have found the solution, here http://learncss.tutsplus.com/lesson/relative-and-absolute-positioning/ the code is as follows

 #wrap_main {
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;width:1200px;
}

I adjusted the Width to that of the most common screen resolution 1280 px and just gave it a relative position so the child divs, could continue to have an absolute position and it seems to work great This helps a lot when like me you are lazy and rather draw a bunch of divs make them look good on the site and then center them for various resolution screens

Answer (score 0):

have found the solution [here](http://learncss.tutsplus.com/lesson/relative-and-absolute-positioning/). The code is as follows

```css
#wrap_main {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap_main">

  other divs

</div>
```

I adjusted the Width to that of the most common screen resolution 1280 px and just gave it a relative position so the child divs, could continue to have an absolute position and it seems to work great This helps a lot when like me you are lazy and rather draw a bunch of divs make them look good on the site and then center them for various resolution screens.